# how to use a .urdf file in gazebo ros?

Tags: ros, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have a .urdf file of a mogel of a robot. I want to use it in gazebo abd ros? I am running on ubuntu 16.04, ros kinetic and gazebo7.

i do not want to build a new model in gazebo, rather i want to use the existing .urdf file in the gazebo simulation through ROS.

Help. I am a novice in ROS, gazebo and ubuntu.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277461/how-to-use-a-.urdf-file-in-gazebo-ros?/) by [anwesha.khasnobish](https://answers.ros.org/users/32888/anwesha.khasnobish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_roslaunch) is tutorial on how to work with gazebo using `roslaunch` command. I would recommend to read the whole thing. What you're looking for right now is in section **Using roslaunch to Spawn URDF Robots**.

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2017-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1